Shipping Large Data With Python Package
I am writing a Python library for scientific calculations. The user should have the possibility to try out these calculations on some test data that (ideally) ships with the Python package. For example:
from mypackge.data import dataset1
from mypackage.science import do_stuff

ds = dataset1() # Downloaded on demand
# result = do_stuff(ds)

The test data are too large that they could be hosted in a Github repository (10-100 MB). For development purposes, I am using dvc and hosting the on a Google Cloud Storage bucket. However, this does not work in production.
Is there a Python library that automatically fetches datasets from a remote bucket? Or more generally speaking, are there any conventions and best practices when shipping test data with Python packages?

In what way would Google's own Python cloud storage client not work for you?

Accessing the bucket per-se is not an issue. My question concerns more issues like associating a dataset with a version of the python package, versioning the data itself, making sure the data is not corrupted, documentation.

Rather than jumping through hoops to try to fetch the library from a remote bucket, I would consider hosting your package as is using Git LFS. It allows you to manage last files.
